# Telerik RadGrid and RadComboBox filtering with a separate data class?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, telerik

I'm trying to implement a `GridBoundColumn` for filtering as described in [this Telerik demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandcombo/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid).

The example queries the database directly using `SqlDataAdapter`, but I want to use an existing class elsewhere in my project, and configure the DataSource of the filter `RadComboBox` in the `RadGrid` to use the LINQ data context common to the rest of my project.

```
namespace MyProject.DataLib
{
    // Data context lives here.
}

namespace MyProject.UI
{
    public partial class MyUI : PageBase
    {
        public class rgcFilterColumn : GridBoundColumn
        {
            ...

            protected void list_ItemsRequested(object o, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
            {
                using (MyProject.DataLib = new DataLib(CurrentUser))  // error CurrentUser
                {
                    ((RadComboBox)o).DataTextField = DataField;
                    ((RadComboBox)o).DataValueField = DataField;
                    ((RadComboBox)o).DataSource = ???;  // LINQ would go here...?
                    ((RadComboBox)o).DataBind();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The user defined by `CurrentUser` has the necessary credentials, however when I try to do this (which I know is wrong):

> Cannot access non-static property 'CurrentUser' in static context.

What would be the best way to accomplish what I want here, as well as clarify my incomplete understanding of why I can't simply talk to my existing data context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/1acb1ff9-4b42-4e93-85ad-d221a571dc50/), should've just looked around more closely.